# Save data to MySQL and update page with that data without refresh

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, jquery

I am trying to save data from a comment form into a MySQL database then update the page with that comment without the user having to refresh. Similar to how Facebook comments work.

I've searched all over the place for an answer to this, but I haven't found one that suites my needs.

Here is the AJAX that submits the form data to the php script:

```
var ajaxSubmit = function(formEl) {
    // fetch where we want to submit the form to
    var url = $(formEl).attr('action');

    // fetch the data for the form
    var data = $(formEl).serializeArray();

    // setup the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            if(rsp.success) {
                alert("Comment Successfully Added!");
        }
    });
  return false;
}
```

I know the page will NOT be updated with this script currently because I am calling an alert. However, when I submit the data I am being taken to the `/ajax/comment.process.php` page which is the page that  calls the `insertComment()` function and inserts the comment to the database.  I have the `alert()` function in the `success()` function right now and I am not even getting that.

What I want is when the comment is submitted, the user doesn't leave the current page, it is just updated with what they just submitted.

Here is the code in `/ajax/comment.process.php'`

```
    session_start();

include_once('../classes/comment.class.php');
include_once('../classes/db.class.php');

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$db = new DBConnection;
$comments = new Comment($db);

$blog_id = intval($_POST['blogID']);

$addCom = $comments->addComment($user_id);

if($addCom === FALSE) {
    $resp = "<span class='error'>Error adding comment</span>";
} else {

    $resp = $comments->getComments($blog_id);
}

return $resp;
```

This script calls the `insertComment()` function which saves the comment to the database, then if that returns true, it calls the `getComments()` function which retrieves the comments for that particular post and stores them in an array.

The comments **ARE** successfully being saved to the database, but I am redirected to the `ajax/comment.process.php` page which is blank. **How can I update the current page with the comment they posted without having to refresh the page?** I thought returning the `$resp` variable would do it then I could just do a `foreach()` loop to display them, however that is clearly not the case.

**EDIT:** I have implemented EVERYTHING suggested in the answers below and I have still not yet fixed this issue. The form is STILL being submitted to `/ajax/comment.process.php` even when I have these three things that should prevent the form from being submitted: `preventDefault();`, `return false;` and `return ajaxSubmit(this);`

Comment: what happens when you remove the rsp.success around the alert?

Comment: How do you call `ajaxSubmit`?

Comment: nothing different happens when I remove the `rsp.success` around the alert. And I am calling `ajaxSubmit()` by adding `onsubmit="ajaxSubmit(this);"` to the `<form>` element

Answer (score 1):

In the ajax you could delete the `dataType: 'json',` and delete the `if(rsp.success) {` and make a simple alert

```
$.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function(data) {
                alert("Comment Successfully Added!");
                alert(data);
        }
});
```

In the php instead of the return you are using, use echo

```
echo $resp;
```

At least you will see if there is an error

After that you could start using the json code

In the php

```
echo json_encode($resp);//as soon as $resp is an array
```

and in the ajax you could alert like this `alert(data.keyofthearray)`

Answer (score 1):

To prevent the form from submitting(which is what is happening)  use `onsubmit="return ajaxSubmit(this);"`

also you have a syntax error in your ajax code. You never close the `if` block

```
var data = $(formEl).serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.success) {
            alert("Comment Successfully Added!");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: adding `return` to the `onsubmit` attribute did prevent the form from redirecting to the process page. However now I am getting a bunch of undefined index errors when trying to echo the array...

Comment: @TyBailey use `.serialize()` instead of `.serializeArray()`

Comment: Okay, I changed that, and now the data is displaying, but it is displaying on the comment.process.php page again...

Comment: @TyBailey it looks like there is an error in you code causing the form to submit, try debugging you code.

Comment: I have tried debugging. That's what I've been doing for the past few hours. The form is still submitting.

Comment: @TyBailey in your question you say you used `preventDefault();`, this will cause a reference error remove it.

Comment: I did, i only tried it once. Now when I have `return false;` it won't even submit through Ajax anymore.